# phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbrench simple alternative for learning

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a PHP application or a Windows application to manage a MySQL database.

I want to help children in learning databases, but MySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin are too hard for begining.

I am looking for an application like phpMyAdmin or Admineer but much simple (ie: Create Table, Column, Row without many functions) - to be easy learnable.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try adminer out

Comment: Just thinking: Wouldn't it be a good idea to show them direct the cli?

Comment: @cybernard - Thank you for the alternative. I'm trying it. At this moment I am building my own application in PHP with MySQL.

Comment: @frlan Thank you for your good idea. I am teaching programming to children and I want to make them to easy understand it before going with "code". In my country we are usually using "Pascal" and an old version of "C" (for DB we are using Fox Pro). I don't want to teach tem old things which aren't used in the present. That's why I teach them MySQL. They are between 16-18 years old and I think that the cli is hard for begining. Thanks again for your ideas.